# "was unexpected at this time" happens only on single computer

Tags: batch-file, cmd

We have got a problem with the following command line (it is executed in a batch file):

```
for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('cmd /c "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do set "jver=%%j"
```

When we execute this line, we get the java version. This works everytime, but now we have a computer here with Windows 10 which can not execute the script and fails at this line and says:

```
8 was unexpected at this time
```

So i assume the script is able to read the 1.8.0_101 java version string but somehow fails. The jver variable is used only once in:

```
if %jver% LSS 8 (
    goto :jdk_wrong_version
)
```

Does anybody know why this strange behavior occurs? Because nearly all machines have no problem with this command. The output when we execute java -version seems fine.

EDIT:

Following lines are executed at the start (So we check if JAVA_HOME is available):

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 1> NUL 2> NUL
if not %errorLevel%==0 goto :java_not_found
```

So the whole script looks like this:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 1> NUL 2> NUL
if not %errorLevel%==0 goto :java_not_found

for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('cmd /c "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do set "jver=%%j"

if %jver% LSS 8 (
    goto :jdk_wrong_version
)
```

Comment: If i remove the `cmd /c` the following error occurs: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: If you remove `cmd /C` from `('cmd /c "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"')`, the remaining string `('"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"')` is executed as `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version` by `for /F`, which is invalid; do not put quotes `""` around the search string `version` and it will work; this is because `for /F` removes the surrounding `''` *and*, if the remaining string appears surrounded by `""`, they will be removed as well...

Comment: Okay. First Question: What happens when the JAVA_HOME path has spaces? The other stuff with removing the characters worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: Nothing special as you have the path quoted anyway; I did not try it though...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the following batch code to safely detect every possible error on determining version of Java:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not defined JAVA_HOME (
    echo Environment variable JAVA_HOME is not defined.
    goto :EOF
)
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" (
    echo File "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" does not exist.
    goto :EOF
)
for /F "tokens=1-3" %%A in ('"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 2^>^&1') do (
    if /I "%%A %%B" == "java version" (
        set "JavaVersion=%%~C"
        goto EvaluateVersion
    )
)
echo Failed to determine version of installed Java.
goto :EOF

:EvaluateVersion
echo Java version is: %JavaVersion%
for /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%I in ("%JavaVersion%") do set "jver=%%I"
echo Main version is: %jver%
rem More batch code.
endlocal
```

Java prints the version to handle **STDERR** instead of handle **STDOUT** which is the reason for `2>&1` with escaping the operators `>` and `&` with `^` in the command line executed by **FOR**.

If the Java version could be determined successfully, the output is something like:

```
Java version is: 1.7.0_55
Main version is: 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But this is basically what we are doing. I am using nearly the same FOR loop. And right before the FOR loop I am doing a similar check where I execute the java.exe directly. (So it would automatically lead to errorlevel 3 and exit.) So this does not help, because our script would already detect those kind of faults.

Comment: Yes, I know that posted batch code is basically the same, but it is not completely the same. For example this batch file explicitly enables command extensions as required for this batch file. And it does not run `java.exe` in subdirectory `bin` in root of current drive if `JAVA_HOME` is not defined and by chance there is for example `C:\bin\java.exe`. Do you have tried this batch file on your machines at all? What was the output on the machine on which your batch script exits with the error?

Comment: What I have also seen in the past was that just `findstr` in a batch file on one machine did not result in execution of `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe` because on that machine an application suite was installed which added its application directory during installation to `PATH` at beginning (instead of appending at end) containing in the application directory also a `findstr` which worked different to Windows `findstr`. Therefore it is always a good idea to write batch files designed for running on many Windows computers being as much independent on `PATH` as possible.

Comment: Try your batch file with `for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 2^>^&1 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /i version') do set "jver=%%j"` and check if there is a difference on result. There is a different `findstr` executed if `jver` is now indeed defined. Otherwise check what manual execution of `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version` and `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 2>&1 | findstr /i version` in a command prompt window outputs on this machine in comparison to other machines on which the batch file works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"` does not exist - possibly `JAVA_HOME` has not been established as an environment variable.

Comment: We execute the following lines at the start:"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version 1> NUL 2> NUL
if not %errorLevel%==0 goto :java_not_found - I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: That code should produce errorlevel `3`. Easy way to see is to add a line `echo "%java_home%"` just before your `for /f ... %%j` so there's no doubt. The symptoms you describe are consistent with `java_home` not being esyablished. Are you trying to perhaps schedule the job? If it's running under a different user or with incorrect access it may have problems...

Comment: Okay. I tried to reproduce this case. I removed my java_home variable. And the `errorlevel 0` works. The `errorlevel 3` does not work. We are not scheduling the job.